# Assign variable in ref.current.measure callback

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, measure

I have a problem with measuring value of my views.
I have to get `pageX` and `pageY` value.

One component looks like:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      updateElementPositions(index)
    })
  }, [])
....

 <StyledElement ref={elementRef[index]} style={style} index={index} type={type}> .....
```

Update element position is a function declared in the context

```
 const updateElementPositions = (index: string) => {
    elementRef[index].current.measure((x: number, y: number, height: number, width: number, pageX: number, pageY: number) => {
      // HERE IS A PROBLEM
    })
  }
```

in this function I would like to assign pageY and pageX value to variable. The problem is that I have a lot of components like that ( about 300 ) and I need to get a dimensions of each element. Hence I can't use setState or methods which causing re-render.I was trying to use `ref`.

```
 elementRef[index].current.measure((x: number, y: number, height: number, width: number, pageX: number, pageY: number) => {
      element.current[index] = {pageX, pageY}
    })
```

But I've encountered this error which is very odd to me

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhPKy.png)

Assign to "normal" variable also causes an error `TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property.`

I'm running out of ideas how can I do it.

I will be grateful if someone will be able to help me :) .

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The `elementRef[index].current` value is currently a reference to an HTMLElement, so you probably shouldn't mutate it. I suggest using a second set of refs to hold the pageX|Y coordinate values. Set the current value of a specific ref by index.

```
elementRef[index].current.measure((x: number, y: number, height: number, width: number, pageX: number, pageY: number) => {
  pageXYRefs.current[index].current = { pageX, pageY }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer , but this is exactly what I'm doing.  (My mistake, I could use better names than `elementRef` and `element` :). )

Comment: @Tomasz Oh shoot, missed that, sorry. Updated my answer.